# Efficiently determine entries of a vector surrounded by the same value as the entry

Tags: r, vector, subset

I can't seem to formulate the title well.

Here is a quick example showing the expected result! 
I can solve the problem myself as you can see, but the code is very inefficient when the vector is big I feel. Is there a smarter way (there is for sure) ?

```
input_data=c(1,1,1,3,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,11,15,15,15,15,15,8,9)

expected_result=rep(TRUE,length(input_data))

for (k in 1:(length(input_data)-2)) {
  if (input_data[k]==input_data[k+1] & input_data[k+1]==input_data[k+2]) {
    expected_result[k+1]=FALSE
  }
}
print(expected_result)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.table approach

**code**

```
library( data.table )
data.table( input = input_data )[, output := ifelse( input == shift( input, type = "lead", fill = FALSE) & input == shift( input, type = "lag", fill = FALSE), TRUE, FALSE)][[2]]
```

**output**

```
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**functionality**

create a `data.table` from the vector `input_data`.
check if previous and next value are equal to current value (using `shift`).
fill in missing values (first and last) as FALSE if previous and next are the same as curret, result = TRUE else, result is FALSE.
write result to a new column names `output`
`[[2]]` is to export the newly created output-column as a vector.

Comment: Thanks @JoelH. When speed is an issue, or when working with a lot of data, `data.table` is always a good package to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Vector solutions,

```
n <- length(input_data)
v0 <- input_data[1:(n-2)]
v1 <- input_data[2:(n-1)]
v2 <- input_data[3:n]
expected_result <- c(TRUE,!((v0==v1)&(v1==v2)),TRUE)
```

and to really minimize,

```
n <- length(input_data)
expected_result <- c(TRUE,!((diff(input_data[-n])==0)&(diff(input_data[-1])==0)),TRUE)
```

Note that you never actually check if the first or last value need updating from the initial `TRUE`, so the `TRUE`s gets padded on both ends.